# improve my PHP/mySQL query to get conversation pairs in PM system

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched for similar topics but either they don't seem to fit into my scenario or I am not able to adapt to my code.

What I am trying to achieve is to get the last message (sent by the member or received by the member), the corresponding member (aka other member) as well as a few other fields to give a summary of the dialogues as seen in the code. My problem is that some members have 100+ messages and my query is currently set to loop through all message to or from the member which is slowing things down a bit. I am asking you for suggestions to rewrite my query so that I only fetch what I want (one [other] member, one message etc) and if possible, the count of the messages between these 2 members. Thank you!

```
$msg_prev_count = 120;
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `m`.`id`, `m`.`from`, `p`.`username`, `m`.`to`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`p`.`last_seen`) AS `last_seen`, SUBSTRING(`m`.`message`,1,{$msg_prev_count}) AS `message`, `m`.`photo_attachment`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`m`.`time`) AS `time`, `m`.`read`, `m`.`replied` 
FROM `messages` `m`, `profiles` `p` 
WHERE `p`.`status`=1 AND `m`.`box`='inbox' 
AND ((`m`.`to`={$_SESSION['member_id']} AND `p`.`id`=`m`.`from`) 
OR (`m`.`from`={$_SESSION['member_id']} AND `p`.`id`=`m`.`to`)) 
ORDER BY `m`.`time` DESC") or die ("error fetching messages: ".mysql_error());
```

This is how I am currently sorting out the messages and discarding all by one!

```
while ($m = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    clear4html($m);
    split_long_words($message['message']);
    $other_member_id = ($m['from'] == $_SESSION['member_id'])?$m['to']:$m['from'];
    if (!is_array($msg[$other_member_id])) {
        $msg[$other_member_id]['msg_count'] = 1;
        $msg[$other_member_id]['time'] = $message['time'];
        foreach ($m as $f => $v) $msg[$other_member_id][$f] = $v;
    }
    else $msg[$other_member_id]['msg_count']++;
}
```

Comment: Have u tried `LIMIT 0 , 1` ?

Comment: This is giving me only one record. What I would like is to get one record per member with whom our member is in communication.

Comment: Its little confusing. Suppose you want to search for Alice. If Bob and Dave have sent msg yo Alice then do you want to get last msg of Bob and Dave ? Can you explain it little more with using some real-type names ? That would be easier.

Comment: That's right. When Alice views her messages (conversations, really), she wants to see "Bob: his last message to her and date", "Dave: his last message to her and date". Also if Alice had sent a message to Mike and that is the last exchange between them, that too will show as "Mike: HER message to Mike and date". A message count for each member would be a bonus.

Comment: I am not very good at sql yet I can say you can use `DISTINCT` for it. You can use it for `\`m\`.\`from\`` or `to` . Thats upon you